# Find and Update Cell in DataTables

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatable, datatables

I need to be able to run a Jquery function to update a value in a certain cell.

Every row in the table has a unique ID number in a column

```
<table id="example">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        ID
      </th>
      <th>
        Count
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>
        ID
      </th>
      <th>
        Count
      </th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <%= a.id %>
      </td>
      <td>
        <%= a.count %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to use Jquery or something to Update the `a.count` in the right Table Row "Without Reloading page" that has the `id` that matches the count of `a.id`

This table will have many rows.

------------Edit-------------

how can i use this to add Class to the Count Cell as well

```
var addId = $('#<%= @table %>').dataTable().fnAddData(<%= @post %>);

var theNode = $('#<%= @table %>').dataTable().fnSettings().aoData[addId[0]].nTr;
theNode.setAttribute('id','<%=  @id %>');
```

solved I did this:

```
var addId = $('#<%= @table %>').dataTable().fnAddData(<%= @post %>);
var theNode = $('#<%= @table %>').dataTable().fnSettings().aoData[addId[0]];
theNode.nTr.setAttribute('id','<%=  @id %>');
theNode.anCells[1].setAttribute('class', 'count');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try adding the id to the row and a class to the cell, something like

```
<tr id="row_#{a.id}">
   <td class="id"><%= a.id...
   <td class="count"><%= a.count...
```

and then you can just use that for the selector, like

```
$("#row_" + id + ' td.count').text(...
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Can i do that with DataTables jquery

Comment: Yep, you'll need to do that wherever you're actually building the table rows - either in the rails view or the javascript.

Comment: how can i add the class to the count Cell? i am using this to add rows after table is already drawn... (See Edit)